# custom class library as an array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, class-library

I'm working with a class library in C# with its own methods and I want to create an array from this library, but I when call it in the main program I cant see its methods.

```
public class ClassLibrary1
{
    public int num;                       

    public ClassLibrary1 ()
    {

    }

    public void Readdata()
    { 
        Console.Write("write a number ");
        num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}
```

program.cs :

```
ClassLibrary1[] arraynumbers = new ClassLibrary1[5];

arraynumbers.Readdata();
```

And I can't use `Readdata()`.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to call methods in your class, you'll have to create at least one instance.  As it is, all you've done is create an array of null references, and then attempt to call your method on the array.  Here's one way you could do it.

```
ClassLibrary1[] arraynumbers = new ClassLibrary1[5];
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
{
    arraynumbers[i] = new ClassLibrary1();
}
arraynumbers[0].Readdata();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `Readdata` the way you've put it because `ClassLibrary1[]` is an ARRAY object, not a `ClassLibrary1` object, in which your method is defined.

You'd have to do something like this instead:

```
arraynumbers[0].Readdata();
```

Answer (score 0):

`Readdata()` is a method of the `ClassLibrary1` instance, not the array that holds `ClassLibrary1` instances.

Answer (score 0):

Methods that are defined on a class may not be called on a collection of that class. If you want to use a method on a collection, consider making an extension method:

```
public static class ClassLibrary1Extensions
{
    public static Readdata(this ClassLibrary[] value)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The "this" keyword in the first parameter allows you to "pretend" this method is on a type of "ClassLibrary1[]" or array. I.e. extending that type.